# Do particles have magnetic poles?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, magnetic-moment, magnetic-monopoles

1. Can single particles have magnetic poles? Or is it only composite structures that can have poles?
2. If a particle can have poles, can the whole particle be classified a pole correspondingly to its electric charge?
3. Or does a particle have both a south pole and a north pole regardless of its electric charge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magnetic *mono*poles - which is to say, isolated North or South magnetic poles - are in principle possible (and would have deep theoretical consequences should they exist) but despite long searches we have yet to find any evidence of their existence.

On the other hand, all stable charged fundamental particles have a magnetic *dipole* moment, which can be understood as a magnetic North and South poles in close (i.e. infinitesimal) proximity. The electron, proton and neutron all have magnetic dipole moments, with the North-South axis pointing along their (quantum mechanical) spin.